# Parallax background and rotating logo not working properly with each other in Chrome

Tags: php, css, wordpress, google-chrome, transform

I'm working on wordpress, the parallax background doesn't work properly on Chrome with the rotating logo. The background doesn't show starting on the 2nd section. The background works fine when I remove the rotating effect of the logo. Please check out the website: http://8liens.com/rotaryQC.com/

It looks perfect on Firefox tho.

header.php //location of the logo

```
 <header class="header-section container scrollblock" <?php if(''!=get_option('colabs_bg_header')) echo " style=\" background-image:url('".get_option('colabs_bg_header')."') \" ";?> >
  <div class="row">

<div class="branding">
</div><!-- .branding -->
  <h1 class="logo spin">
<a href="<?php echo $site_url;?>">
  <?php
  if ('logo'==get_option('colabs_logotitle')) echo '<img src="' . get_option('colabs_logo') . '" alt="' . $site_title . '" />';
  else echo $site_title;      
  ?>
  </a>
</h1>
```

theme-functions.php //location of the backgrounds

```
  $wp_customize->add_section( 'background_settings', array(
    'title'    => __( 'Background Settings', 'colabsthemes' ),
    'priority' => 50,
  ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'colabs_bg_header', array(
    'default' => get_option( 'colabs_bg_header' ),
    'type'        => 'option',
    'capability'  => 'manage_options',
  ) );

  $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'colabs_bg_header', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Background section Header', 'colabsthemes' ),
    'section'  => 'background_settings',
    'settings' => 'colabs_bg_header',
    'priority' => 1,
  ) ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'colabs_bg_team', array(
    'default' => get_option( 'colabs_bg_team' ),
    'type'        => 'option',
    'capability'  => 'manage_options',
  ) );
```

style.css //location of the logo css

```
.branding {
  height: 350px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align:center;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

.logo a {
  position:relative;
}

.spin { 
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: spin 15s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: spin 15s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: spin 15s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: spin 15s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
         -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
         -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.site-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #909090;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is my first work. :)